# How to export a Google AutoML Text Classification model?

Tags: google-cloud-automl, automl

I just finished training my AutoML Text Classification model (single-label).

I was planning to run a Batch Prediction using the console, but I just found out how expensive that will be because I have over 300,000 text records to analyze.

So now I want to export the model to my local machine and run the predictions there.

I found [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export) to export "AutoML Tabular Models" and "AutoML Edge Models". But there is nothing available for text classification models.

I tried following the "AutoML Tabular Model" instructions because that looked like the closest thing to a text classification model, but I could not find the "Export" button that was supposed to exist on the model detail page.

So I have some questions regarding this:

1. How do I export a AutoML Text Classification model?
2. Is a AutoML Text Classification model the same thing as an AutoML Tabular model? They seem very similar because my text classifiction model used tabular CSV to assign labels and train the model.
3. If I cannot export AutoML Text Classification model (urgh!), can I train a new "Tabular" model to do the same thing?

Comment: Hello, did you ever have success by using the Tabular model? Do you know if that model come with the same natural language processing? It's a shame that issue is just being left to stagnate because this would be a useful feature.

Comment: @Simon Sorry I did not find a solution. But also I haven't looked at ML stuff for a while, so things might have changed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think they have. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Currently, there is no feature to export an AutoML text classification model. Already a feature request exists, you can follow its progress on this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/168860629).
2. Both the models are quite similar. A tabular data classification model analyzes your tabular data and returns a list of categories that describe the data. A text data classification model analyzes text data and returns a list of categories that apply to the text found in the data. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/automl-model-types) for more information about AutoML model types.
3. Yes, you can do the same thing in an AutoML tabular data classification model if your training data is in tabular CSV file format. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-tabular) for more information about how to prepare tabular training data.

If your model trained successfully in an AutoML tabular data classification, you can find an `Export` option at the top. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-model-tabular#export) for more information about how to export tabular classification models.

[image]